# OAuth2 Client Credentials or permanent token for a system invoking my API?

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, client, token, credentials

We have a Spring Boot API, at which users authenticate with their credentials under the JWT scheme before consuming it's endpoints. Now, we are implementing a new system (a chatbot) which needs to consume those endopoints before returning it's answers to the users. My question is, should we implement an authorization server and a resource server as the OAuth2 Client Credentials Grants specification suggests? In that case, will our chatbot need to authenticate periodically using it's cliendid and secret? We were thinking about a permanent token for the client chatbot avoiding the permanent authentication. We don't want the client to have to obtain a token every time it has to call the API, we would like to give the client an already generated token which it will use in every request thus avoidindg the token obtention steps. Would this approach be unsafe? Which approach is more advisable under this scenario?

Comment: *"users authenticate with their credentials under the JWT scheme"* I don't know bout this flow, would you detail? Also, if a user is involved, `client_credentials` is probably **not** what you need: forwarding the access-token received by the first service is probably a much better option.

Comment: I mean it follows this flow:  https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt . But now we want to add functionality, so that not only users can authenticate, but also client apps following the Client Credentials flow. Problem is the system now have to validate the original tokens and the ones issued by the new authentication server for Client Credentials.

Comment: This tutorial is pretty bad, forget about the solution you set up so far and use OAuth2 (no you are not using OAuth2 just because you are using JWTs: you can use OAuth2 without JWTs and, as in the case of this tutorial, using JWTs in flows that are not OAuth2 and known for exposing apps to a all bunch of vulnerabilities).

Answer (score 0):

As I know and also as a best practice is to use `OAuth2 Client Credentials` because it is designed and is more secured if you have just these 2 ways of doing it:

> This flow(OAuth2 Client Credentials) is useful for systems that need to perform API operations
> when no user is present. It can be nightly operations, or other that
> involve contacting OAuth protected APIs.

But these api calls(chatbot) are triggered by final user if I got you correctly and in this case you have to implement `Authorization Code Flow`.

If it is spring based application you can start from documentation about starters that `spring-boot` provide.

[Oauth2 - Resource Server/Client Part](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html)

[spring-authorization-server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

**The flow used in [the tutorial you used](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt) is not OAuth2** and the solution exposed is considered a worst practice at many places because of the security vulnerabilities inherent to using JWTs as session for a frontend. Forget about it.

If you want your app to comply with OAuth2, all REST APIs services should be configured as resource servers.

If your frontend is rendered server-side, configure it as an OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login`.

If your frontend is a single page application or a mobile application, then it should not be an OAuth2 client (these can only be "public" OAuth2 clients, [usage of which is now discouraged](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390)). You should use a **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend as "confidential" OAuth2 client with something to bridge between session + CSRF based security (between the frontend and the BFF) and token based security (between the BFF and resource servers). `spring-cloud-gateway` can be used for that purpose, with `oauth2Login`, CSRF protection and the `TokenRelay` filter. I wrote [a tutorial for that on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).

For inter resource servers communication, two options:

- forward the access token from the original request (request from service-A to service-B made on behalf of the resource owner who originated the request to service-A)
- get a new access token using client_credentials flow (request from service-A to service-B made by service-A in its own name, without the context of a user)

The implementation details of these two options depend on the REST client you choose (current recommended Spring clients are `WebClient`, `RestClient` and `@FeignClient`). Refer to the respective docs, once you chose your REST client and authorization strategy.